# 301 hidden Redirect with Parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

A image gallery moves to a new place.

Old:

```
album_showpage.php?pic_id=1
```

New:

```
/image/gallery/image_page.php?image_id=1
```

The new file

```
image_page.php
```

make a 301 redirect to something like this:

```
/category-1/image-1.html
```

I need a hidden redirect from old to new.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^album_showpage.php?pic_id=([0-9]+) /image/gallery/image_page.php?image_id=$1 [L]
```

But album_showpage.php gives me always a 404.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pic_id=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^album_showpage\.php$ /image/gallery/image_page.php?image_id=%1 [L]
```